# I want to use a jquery function for th:onclick ... I can not speak English well

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL6ri.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRbLC.png)

1)in the second picture Even fn_del is not recognized.

2)I want to use jquery function in the <button id="fileDel" th:onclick= part, please help

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Can you add the code/text from your pictures to your question.  That will make it easier for people to access the key parts of your question, and reproduce your problem to better analyse it (as described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating input parameters with same id so you need to class or other attribute to identify FILE_NO, FILE_NAME. Also you can use just button's onclick action.

```
<input onclick="fn_del()"/>
```

there will be more than one button and input parameters because you define in a foreach loop.

Make sure that files variable have FILE_NO as well.